# Modelica playground "Internal error function lexer failed"

Tags: modelica

I'm trying to use the Modelica playground to build a double pendulum model but it is erroring with "Internal error function lexer failed".  How do I fix this?  I assume it's a problem with my model but perhaps it's a problem with the playground?  I don't know.

```
  constant Real speed=0.2;
  constant Real gravity(unit="m/s2")=9.8 * speed;
  constant Real length(unit="m")=1;
  constant Real length2(unit="m")=1;
  constant Real mass(unit="kg")=1;
  constant Real mass2(unit="kg")=1;
  Real angle(unit="rad");
  Real momentum(unit="kg m/s");
  Real angle2(unit="rad");
  Real momentum2(unit="kg m/s");

initial equation
  angle = 130 * (3.142 / 180);
  momentum = 0;
  angle2 = 0; // relative to vertical
  momentum2 = 0;
equation
  der(angle) = (6/(mass * length^2)) * ((2 * momentum - 3 * cos(angle - angle2) * momentum2)/(16 - 9 * cos(angle - angle2)^2));
  der(momentum) = -0.5 * mass * length^2 * (der(angle) * der(angle2) * sin(angle - angle2) + (3 * (gravity / length) * sin(angle)));

  der(angle2) = (6/(mass2 * length2^2)) * ((8 * momentum2 - 3 * cos(angle - angle2) * momentum)/(16 - 9 * cos(angle - angle2)^2));
  der(momentum2) = -0.5 * mass2 * length2^2 * (-der(angle) * der(angle2) * sin(angle - angle2) + (3 * (gravity / length2) * sin(angle2)));

  //annotation(experiment(StartTime=0,StopTime=200)); // todo find out how this works
```

[Link to playground](https://playground.modelica.university/?model=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%253D%253D&report=QSBwZW5kdWx1bSBpbiBNb2RlbGljYS4gIFByZXNzIHRoZSAiUGxheSIgYnV0dG9uIHRvIGFuaW1hdGUuCgo8c3ZnIGhlaWdodD0iNDAwIiB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld2JveD0iLTIwMCAtMjAwIDQwMCA0MDAiPgogIDxjaXJjbGUgY3g9IjAiIGN5PSIwIiByPSIxMCIgc3Ryb2tlPSJibGFjayIgc3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoPSIzIiBmaWxsPSJyZWQiIC8%252BCiAgPGcgdHJhbnNmb3JtID0gInRyYW5zbGF0ZSgwLCAwKSByb3RhdGUoe3sgOTAgKyAobm93LmFuZ2xlICogKDE4MC8zLjE0MikpIH19IDAgMCkiPgogICAgPHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iLTMiIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAiIGhlaWdodD0iNiIgc3Ryb2tlPSJibGFjayIgLz4KICAgIDxnIHRyYW5zZm9ybSA9ICJ0cmFuc2xhdGUoMTAwLCAwKSByb3RhdGUoe3sgbm93LmFuZ2xlMiAqICgxODAvMy4xNDIpIH19IDAgMCkiPgogICAgICA8cmVjdCB4PSIwIiB5PSItMyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCIgaGVpZ2h0PSI2IiBzdHJva2U9ImJsYWNrIiAvPgogICAgPC9nPiAKICA8L2c%252BCjwvc3ZnPgoKPGNoYXJ0IHNpZ25hbHM9ImFuZ2xlIj48L2NoYXJ0Pgo8Y2hhcnQgc2lnbmFscz0iYW5nbGUyIj48L2NoYXJ0PgoKPGNoYXJ0IHNpZ25hbHM9InZlbG9jaXR5Ij48L2NoYXJ0Pgo8Y2hhcnQgc2lnbmFscz0idmVsb2NpdHkyIj48L2NoYXJ0Pgo%253D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is in the unit definition of the "momentum" variables. It should be `unit="kg.m/s"` instead of `unit="kg m/s"`. The fixed code is:

```
  constant Real speed=0.2;
  constant Real gravity(unit="m/s2")=9.8 * speed;
  constant Real length(unit="m")=1;
  constant Real length2(unit="m")=1;
  constant Real mass(unit="kg")=1;
  constant Real mass2(unit="kg")=1;
  Real angle(unit="rad");
  Real momentum(unit="kg.m/s");
  Real angle2(unit="rad");
  Real momentum2(unit="kg.m/s");

initial equation
  angle = 130 * (3.142 / 180);
  momentum = 0;
  angle2 = 0; // relative to vertical
  momentum2 = 0;
equation
  der(angle) = (6/(mass * length^2)) * ((2 * momentum - 3 * cos(angle - angle2) * momentum2)/(16 - 9 * cos(angle - angle2)^2));
  der(momentum) = -0.5 * mass * length^2 * (der(angle) * der(angle2) * sin(angle - angle2) + (3 * (gravity / length) * sin(angle)));

  der(angle2) = (6/(mass2 * length2^2)) * ((8 * momentum2 - 3 * cos(angle - angle2) * momentum)/(16 - 9 * cos(angle - angle2)^2));
  der(momentum2) = -0.5 * mass2 * length2^2 * (-der(angle) * der(angle2) * sin(angle - angle2) + (3 * (gravity / length2) * sin(angle2)));

  //annotation(experiment(StartTime=0,StopTime=200)); // todo find out how this works
```

Seems there is room for improvement in the error message...